# detect color space with openCV

Tags: colors, opencv, space

how can I see the color space of my image with openCV ?

I would like to be sure it is RGB, before to convert to another one using cvCvtColor() function

thanks

Comment: I see below you are pulling the images from a phone. What format are they in? It no longer sounds as though you are pulling actual `IplImage` structs -- how are you getting the images into OpenCV?

Comment: even I am wondering if the images I am taking from my webcam are saved as RGB or BGR? (did you happen to find your solution by any chance?)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Unfortunately, OpenCV doesn't provide any sort of indication as to the color space in the IplImage structure, so if you blindly pick up an IplImage from somewhere there is just no way to know how it was encoded. Furthermore, no algorithm can definitively tell you if an image should be interpreted as HSV vs. RGB - it's all just a bunch of bytes to the machine (should [this](http://www.linesandcolors.com/images/2006-06/mandelbrot_450.jpg) be HSV or RGB?). I recommend you wrap your IplImages in another struct (or even a C++ class with templates!) to help you keep track of this information. If you're really desperate and you're dealing only with a certain type of images (outdoor scenes, offices, faces, etc.) you could try computing some statistics on your images (e.g. build histogram statistics for natural RGB images and some for natural HSV images), and then try to classify your totally unknown image by comparing which color space your image is closer to.

Comment: thanks, so these pictures are taken by a smart phone using google android. I supposed they are RGB images, is that correct ? RGB is the most common color space right ?

thanks

Comment: Again, there's really no way to tell without actually displaying the images, but I think that RGB is a pretty safe assumption - it's what most people think of when they talk about a three channel color space. I would be pretty surprised if it was anything else.

Answer (score 7):

txandi makes an interesting point.  OpenCV has a BGR colorspace which is used by default.  This is similar to the RGB colorspace except that the B and R channels are physically switched in the image.  If the physical channel ordering is important to you, you will need to convert your image with this function: cvCvtColor(defaultBGR, imageRGB, CV_BGR2RGB).

Answer (score 4):

As [rcv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122706/detect-color-space-with-opencv/2137355#2137355) said, there is no method to programmatically detect the color space by inspecting the three color channels, unless you have *a priori* knowledge of the image content (e.g., there is a marker in the image whose color is known). If you will be accepting images from unknown sources, you must allow the user to specify the color space of their image. A good default would be to assume RGB.

If you modify any of the pixel colors before display, and you are using a non-OpenCV viewer, you should probably use `cvCvtColor(src,dst,CV_BGR2RGB)` after you have finished running all of your color filters. If you are using OpenCV for the viewer or will be saving the images out to file, you should make sure they are in BGR color space.

Answer (score 3):

The [IplImage struct](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/basic_structures.html#iplimage) has a field named `colorModel` consisting of 4 chars. Unfortunately, OpenCV ignores this field. But you can use this field to keep track of different color models.

Comment: the link is broken now. In opencv4 it is not available anymore https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/14344

Answer (score 2):

I basically split the channels and display each one to figure out the color space of the image I'm using. It may not be the best way, but it works for me.

For detailed explanation, you can refer the below link.

https://dryrungarage.wordpress.com/2018/03/11/image-processing-basics/